# How to call a function when loading of audio in react audio tag is failing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I am loading audio from a s3 bucket. Below is my audio tag.

```
<audio ref={audioRef} controls src={audioUrl} />
```

Sometimes audio tag is not able to load the audio from the **audioUrl**.

I want to call a function. only when loading fails. Which even should I use?

If you need any more information then please inform me

Comment: Try normal javascript based `onerror` [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_error.asp)

Answer (score 2):

There are onError and onAbort Event in audio element . Try it

onemptied.
onerror.
onstalled.
onsuspend.

Refer.. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror_media.asp